# Midnight semantics

Tags: time, semantics

I received an email with a discount code valid 'until Saturday midnight' but when I went to use it on Saturday lunchtime it had expired already, at 00:00 Saturday morning.

My understanding was that saying 'midnight' on a day it usually refers to the end of the day (23:59) rather than the start of the day (00:01), at least in the UK where I am it's generally used in that way. 'Midnight tomorrow' for example would refer to midnight tomorrow night. **HOWEVER** I do understand that technically it is correct either way as it refers to 00:00.

The email was however from a French company - is it common for it to be referred to in this way elsewhere in the world? What is the general consensus for the usage of 'midnight'?

Comment: In France, "jusqu'à samedi minuit" also refers to *till Saturday 23:59:59*.

Comment: @IconDaemon as stated in the question, I'm in the UK :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Midnight is the end of the day, not the beginning: it follows the day's morning, afternoon, and evening. That's what most people *think*, anyway, and that's what most people would *assume* in the scenario you describe.

Technically, though, there seems to be no rule. I see how some unscrupulous merchants might want to take advantage of that, the idea being to get you to the store: once you're at the store, you might buy something anyway, discount or no discount.

Comment: Why did I think this answer was from Ricky as soon as I read "some unscrupulous merchants...."?  +1 for cutting to the chase.

Comment: @ab2: Because anyone other than Ricky would have written "some trustworthy, altruistic, saintly merchants ..."

Comment: Most businesses set a deadline of 11:59 or 12:01 in order to avoid this problem.

Comment: *Midnight is the end of the day, not the beginning: it follows the day's morning, afternoon, and evening.* This is correct both in terms of regular use of language, and also "mathematically" - in the same way that the year 2000 was the last year of the 20th Century, not the first year of the 21st C. So 23:59 is the end of the second-last minute, and 00:00 is the end of the last minute of a day. However there is great ambiguity as noted, and "Midnight Saturday" could well be the end of Friday Night, for quite a lot of uses.

Comment: Where I live, people generally disambiguate saying "midnight *to* Saturday", when referring to the early midnight of Saturday. "Saturday midnight" and "midnight Saturday" referring to the late midnight. Admittedly though, I haven't heard this disambiguation used many other regions.